# translate sentences into logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

If I would like to translate the English sentence below into a predicate logic formula

"The parents of a green dragon are green"

Using predicates *dragon*, *childOf* and *green*, how would I go about this?

I understand that it may help to work the sentence into something that looks like logic, but I am getting stuck at how to represent "parents" as it is not a predicate.

Do either of these translations help me? Are they correct interpretations of the original sentence?

If a dragon is the child of green parents then it is green.
All dragons who are children of green parents are green.

```
∀(X) . dragon(X) ∧ childOf(X)  ...?
```

please help. thank you in advance

Comment: There seems to be an implicit assumption that the parents of dragons are dragons.

Comment: I think the main idea is that "X is a child of Y" means the same thing as "Y is a parent of X".  So instead of the "parentOf" predicate you can use the "childOf" predicate instead.  (Note by the way that childOf must be a *binary* predicate.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\forall x (\exists y (y \text{is a green dragon} \wedge y \text{ is child of } x) \rightarrow  x\text{is a green dragon})$$

Comment: You misinterpreted the statement, it should be understood as "If a dragon is a parent of (any) green dragon, then the first dragon is green".

Comment: I don't think there's anything in the statement that insists that only dragons can be parents of green dragons. Perhaps the parent of a green dragon is a green basilisk.

Comment: There is no misinterpretation that is what the sentence says.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following English paraphrase, which seems (to me) equivalent to the given formulation:

"For all x and y, if x is a dragon and x is green and x is a child of y, then y is green."

Answer (score 1):

Being a parent is a relation. Let $D$ be the predicate of being a dragon, $G$ being the predicate of being green and $P$ being the "is a parent of" relation.

Then we have: $\forall x\forall y (G(x)\wedge D(x)\wedge P(y,x))\implies G(y)$

Comment: The OP has provided a different predicate to convey your $P$ and your parentheses are misplaced/missing.